# Xamarin / Service / BroadcastReceiver / Web Service

Tags: web-services, service, xamarin, broadcastreceiver

I have a service that runs every 1 hour, the service is properly activated.
The problem is that this service needs to access a web service.
The problem occurs only when you start the service through the BOOT_COMPLETED to start the service by a button on the app work perfectly.
I am unable to identify the reason but it does not access, anyone have any idea what can be?
The service works by BOOT_COMPLETED only if it does not implement access to web service

```
[Service]
[IntentFilter(new String[]{"xxxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxxxxx"})]
public class Notificacao : Service
{
static readonly int tempoEspera = 30000;
Timer _timer;

  public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent,     StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
  {
      try
      {
          _timer = new Timer(o => { VerificarNotificacao(); },
              null,
              0,
              tempoEspera);
      } catch { }

      return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
  }

  public override void OnDestroy()
  {
      base.OnDestroy();

      _timer.Dispose();
      _timer = null;
  }

  public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
  {
      // This example isn't of a bound service, so we just return NULL.
      return null;
  }

  private void VerificarNotificacao(){
      // *********Call web service ***********
  }
}
```

Comment: When it can't access the service, does it return an error or exception?  Does it just timeout?  What is the specific failure behavior?

Comment: Unfortunately does not return error or exception to at least know the reason for the problem.
I used the logs to try to identify the error any more relevant to the app is returned to the log beyond the message put to identify the beginning of the process.
I put log return on error handling or more passes there.

Comment: The problem was on schedule.
Was passing a parameter to the Webservice that had not yet been informed, he was being informed only after the user login.
Thanks for listening.